# How to separate table rows with a line

Tags: html, html-table

I have a basic HTML table which contains table rows. My goal is to separate those table rows with a visible line (for better readability of the content).

How could I do this?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

There are several ways to do that. Using HTML alone, you can write

```
<table border=1 frame=void rules=rows>
```

or, if you want a border above the first row and below the last row too,

```
<table border=1 frame=hsides rules=rows>
```

This is rather inflexible, though; you cannot e.g. make the lines dotted this way, or thicker than one pixel. This is why in the past people used special separator rows, consisting of nothing but some content intended to produce a line (it gets somewhat dirty, especially when you need to make rows e.g. just a few pixels high, but it’s possible).

For the most of it, people nowadays use CSS `border` properties for the purpose. It’s fairly simple and cross-browser. But note that to make the lines continuous, you need to prevent spacing between cells, using either the `cellspacing=0` attribute in the `table` tag or the CSS rule `table { border-collapse: collapse; }`. Removing such spacing may necessitate adding some padding (with CSS, preferably) *inside* the cells.

At the simplest, you could use

```
<style>
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr { 
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px 0;
}
</style>
```

This puts a border above the first row and below the last row too. To prevent that, add e.g. the following into the style sheet:

```
tr:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}
tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Just style the border of the rows:

```
​table tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}​

table tr:last-child { 
    border-bottom: none; 
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tcwnR/).

Edited as mentioned by @pkyeck. The second style avoids the line under the last row. Maybe you are looking for this.

Comment: maybe add a `table tr:last-child { border-bottom: none; }` to avoid that the last `<tr>` is underlined

Comment: @cem, Thank you, but where to put this style? In the css ? I am trying but nothing changes.

Answer (score 14):

You could use the `border-bottom` css property.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

table tr:last-child {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Foo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Bar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to use CSS.

In my opinion when you have a table often it is good with a separate line each side of the line.

Try this code:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr class="row"><td>row 1</td></tr>
    <tr class="row"><td>row 2</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
    border:1px solid black; 
}
```

Bye

Andrea

Comment: Thank you, but where to put this style? In the css ? I am trying but nothing changes.

Comment: The style is a CSS style so you can do two different thing to insert a CSS style inside your HTML page: 

**1) Using CSS style sheets embedded:**  You have to add the add your style inside the head of your HTML Page...something like that:

<html>
<head>
<title>Inserire i fogli di stile in un documento</title>
<style type="text/css"> 
.row {
    border:1px solid black; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr class="row"><td>row 1</td></tr>
    <tr class="row"><td>row 2</td></tr>
</table>
</body>

Comment: **2) Using external CSS:** Something like:
<html>
<head>
<title>Inserire i fogli di stile in un documento</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

You have to create another style.css (that you are linking int your html file using the link tag) file that contains the code:

.row {
    border:1px solid black; 
}

This solution is better because if you have many style in your page you are separating the HTML code from the CSS Style code...you are separating the layout from the style...all is much clear

Comment: I suggest you to read some HTML\CSS development guide because this is very base argument :-)

Comment: I needed to add cellspacing = 0 in the table properties to get this to work.

Answer (score 3):

**HTML**

```
<table cellspacing="0">
  <tr class="top bottom row">
    <td>one one</td>
    <td>one two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="top bottom row">
    <td>two one</td>
    <td>two two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="top bottom row">
    <td>three one</td>
    <td>three two</td>
  </tr>

</table>​
```

**CSS**:

```
tr.top td { border-top: thin solid black; }
tr.bottom td { border-bottom: thin solid black; }
tr.row td:first-child { border-left: thin solid black; }
tr.row td:last-child { border-right: thin solid black; }​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/P2GZX/)**

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use CSS try this one between your rows:

```
    <tr>
    <td class="divider"><hr /></td>
    </tr>
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Style the row-element with css:

```
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
```

Comment: Thank you, but where to put this style? In the css ? I am trying but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Set colspan to your number of columns, and background color as you wish

```
<tr style="background: #aaa;">
 <td colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
```